# Project building in NetBeans8.1 is too slow

Tags: netbeans-8

Note: I did some research, and I found nothing on this type of problem.

When I try to clean and build or run a program, it varies between 20 and 30 seconds to do that. (I'm coding in C and C++)
The last time I tried to clean and build, it took 23 seconds to do it. Building is faster, it takes 10 seconds. Running a program takes 25 seconds.
This started happening a few days ago out of nowhere, I had 3 plugins but they were all just changing my NetBeans skin. What can I do to make my IDE work faster?

It spends most of the time at this part:

cd 'E:\projekti\helloworld'
C:\cygwin642\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean

and this:

cd 'E:\projekti\helloworld'
C:\cygwin642\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug

What can I do to make this go away?

Comment: has it done this from the start or is it something that is just happening?

Comment: It started happening about 4 days ago, but I didn't do anything out of ordinary.

Comment: Ok I just figured out that I installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and everything got messy. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Malwarebytes Antimalware turn it off. Deactivating its functions doesn't help. You need it to quit it completely. You will gain 12x to 20x build speed increase. It doesn't affect speed of netbeans startup but it drastically speeds up netbeans cleaning iand building. I also reccomend quiting netbeans and deleting entrie cache folder (in windows inside: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\NetBeans). Restart windows. Projects will scan for looong time. Don't quit netbeans, do not write any code or reconfigure your projects. Just wait till scan finishes. Restart netbeans. Scanning should be faster now. Remember, do not run malwarebytes antimalware when you use netbeans. Make sure Antimalware icon is not on your tray.